# Importing plottools

Tags: python

I am trying to `import plottools` for use in jupyter notebook.
I installed the library using `pip install plottools` as written in the documentation. I installed it in Anaconda prompt and it was successful. I tried to import the library but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3369 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Input In [4] in <cell line: 6>
    import plottools

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plottools\__init__.py:21 in <module>
    from .plottools import *

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plottools\plottools.py:49
    """
       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 336-337: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I have tried installing it using pip3 and it responded that the requiremnets are already met.

Comment: Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the package has invalid escaping characters in the docstring the `\U` here:

`C:\Users\yourusername\.matplotlib`

Goto your file `\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plottools\plottools.py` and delete the line.